How to create reusable html block in laravel statamic so I can use it on different pages in vuejs?
I am trying to create a CMS using laravel statamic and vuejs. What I am trying to achieve is I want to build reusable html blocks; for example I want to build a banner image block which admin should be able to use on different pages and lest they want banner in home page and about page. All they need to do from admin panel is import that block and then change its content dynamically also and their work gets finished and we use statamic restful API to show those two banners on home and about page respectively. Is it possible in statamic to do that?
Need to build a functionality where admin can move blocks and also able to change its content.
I thought this can be achieve via blueprints or maybe some reusable fieldsets but not sure if I am right or wrong.

What have you tried so far? What isn't working about what you have attempted? the question needs details and clarity.

Yes, that's possible using the Replicator fieldtype. You can configure "sets" for each of the page builder blocks, each with their own sets of fields.
In the REST API, you'll be able to get the data for all of the blocks. The type key will determine the current set/block type.
I hope that makes sense! If you have any more questions, there's a very active Statamic community on Discord with community members willing to help.

hey thanks for the answer. First it didnt make sense to me but then i looked at the start kit of statmic. That explains everything what you have said. Tahnks for the help.
https://statamic.com/starter-kits/afan-ajdari/blogo
